# Difference between .toPromise() sync way and pipe async way

Tags: angular, typescript, synchronization, pipe, observable

### What are the difference between `.toPromise().then()` async way and `pipe` async way

Here am using a `toPromise().then()` method to `synchronous` call

```
deleteErrorList(errordetails) {
        return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'RemoveErrorList', errordetails, this.requestOptions)
            .toPromise().then((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
    }
```

HTML - `*ngFor="let variantLabel of elementData.elementDataCollection"`

---

But my one of the colleague give me a suggestion to use with `map()` and `asyncpipe` pattern for `observables` instead of using `toPromise()`.

So I have changed my code with using `.map()` instead of `toPromise()` like

```
deleteErrorList(errordetails) {
            return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'RemoveErrorList', errordetails, this.requestOptions)
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                });
        }
```

HTML - `*ngFor="let variantLabel of elementData.elementDataCollection | async"`

---

> but the code helps to same process for `sync` call. ***But we don't know what is the difference? is it only help to support for `Observable`? And which one is the best way?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` the `| async` pipe will call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` on the host component to make change detection include this component on the next turn.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. So It means we can pass the data to one component to another component as sae as `@input` and `@output` pattern?. If yes, then I'll go to ask another one question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. That's not related to `@Input()` or `@Output()`, it's related to callbacks that change your components model to get the changes reflected in the HTML.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for it. And can you tell me where we could be use the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: u can use it on component

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: but calling a method using the expression with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is really a bad idea, it won't detect any changes once the application has rendered completely

Comment: `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` is almost always the right strategy to use when performance matters. You can always call `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` when you need the view updated.